# We are twins with different places of birth mentioned in the passport with the same date

Tags: b1-b2-visas

We are twins with different places of birth mentioned in the passport with the same date. Both places of birth are in India. Is there going to be an issue? I have already traveled to a few countries.

My brother lives in the US on an H1B and I want to visit him on a B1 visa. Will there be a problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just get one set of documents corrected to your actual place of birth? Or were you actually born in two different physical locations?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas This is India, "just correcting" documents is a bureaucratic nightmare of Kafkaesque proportions.

Comment: I mean, it's not impossible, and if it turns out to actually be a problem in the long term for whatever reason, it sometimes ends up worthwhile to just fix the darn thing.

Comment: I am sorry for the personal question, but is it an error? or did it really happen?

Answer (score 8):

**There will not be a problem.**  Your application will be assessed on its merits regarding your income, ties to India etc; they're not even going to see your brother's passport.

In the very unlikely event of being asked about this though, it would be good to have a clear explanation of what happened.  (And Travel.SE wants to know too!)